# Current sensing

Tags: microcontroller, home-automation

I am a newbie trying to figure out how to sense current using MCU whenever there is a current flow in a power cable,I tried the aircore transformer bt its size is too big to include in my project, can you guys suggest me any solution ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try a Hall effect type IC, P/N:  ACS712ELCTR-30A-T
It 66mV/Amp, 0-5V. Positive and negative current, up to 30Amps
It can sense DC and AC current...

Comment: Thanks hassan789,but when I checked last time I read somewhere that I had to stepdown the voltage right?

Comment: if you have a MCU with a 5V adc, and the current you are trying to detect is less than 30Amps, you don't have to do anything, but pass the current through this chip, and measure using the MCU adc

Answer (score 0):

I use the SCT013 current sensors from www.yhdc.com, they have a good range with either 0-1V or 0-50mA outputs for primary current in range fro 0-100A

Comment: I tried it Laurie, but I needed a more compact component that I can easily integrate within my circuit board so I chose the hall effect sensor